# updating CORS policy of HTTP API via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Amazon has released the ability to create HTTP API's via API gateway. On their website they describe that it is possible to create an HTTP API via AWS CLI: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-examples.html#http-api-examples.cli.quick-create.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

`aws apigatewayv2 create-api --name my-api --protocol-type HTTP --target arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:123456789012:function:function-name`

For REST API's I know it is possible to update the CORS policy via AWS CLI. I was wondering if it is also possible to change/create the CORS policy for HTTP API's via AWS CLI?

I want to use HTTP API's because it saves a lot of money!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can certainly update the CORS policy via the CLI. I've been able to successfully update it using `aws apigatewayv2 update-api --api-id API-ID --cors-configuration AllowOrigins="*"`. My main problem is that the API Gateway doesn't appear to be _respecting_ this policy, as all of my pre-flight options requests are getting a 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$ aws2 apigatewayv2 update-api --api-id $API_ID --cors-configuration AllowHeaders="*",AllowMethods=GET,POST,AllowOrigins="*",MaxAge=3600

{
    "ApiEndpoint": "https://$API_ID.execute-api.$AWS_REGION.amazonaws.com",
    "ApiId": $API_ID,
    "ApiKeySelectionExpression": "$request.header.x-api-key",
    "CorsConfiguration": {
        "AllowHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST"
        ],
        "AllowOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "MaxAge": 3600
    },
    "CreatedDate": "2020-01-28T17:41:35+00:00",
    "Name": "http-api",
    "ProtocolType": "HTTP",
    "RouteSelectionExpression": "$request.method $request.path",
    "Tags": {}
}
```